# Are Canadians allowed to travel into the US visa-free as usual amid the current coronavirus situation as it is?

Tags: usa, covid-19, canadian-citizens

Normally Canadians are able to enter into the US for up to six months at a time without a visa as long as they aren't working. How has the covid pandemic affected this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are Canadians allowed to travel into the US visa-free as usual amid the current coronavirus situation as it is?

Yes (assuming coming straight from Canada), but only for essential travel if using land borders. Air travel to the US is unrestricted.

https://www.dhs.gov/news/2020/09/18/fact-sheet-dhs-measures-border-limit-further-spread-coronavirus

> Release Date:  September 18, 2020
>
> Updated Dates:  April 21, 2020, May 20, 2020, June 16, 2020, July 16,
> 2020, August 14, 2020 Original Date:  March 23, 2020
>
> In order to limit the further spread of coronavirus, the U.S. has
> reached agreements with both Canada and Mexico to **limit all
> non-essential travel across borders**. Working closely and
> collaboratively, the Department of Homeland Security is part of a
> North American approach to stop the spread of the virus.
>
> Additionally, CBP will no longer detain illegal immigrants in our
> holding facilities and will immediately return these aliens to the
> country they entered from – Canada or Mexico. Where such a return is
> not possible, CBP will return these aliens to their country of origin.
>
> These measures were implemented on March 21, 2020 and were originally
> in place for 30 days, subject to reevaluation and further extension in
> light of the fluid nature of the coronavirus pandemic.  On April 20,
> 2020, these measures were extended for an additional 30 days; on May
> 19, 2020, these measures were extended until June 22, 2020; on June
> 16, 2020, these measures were once again extended until July 21, 2020;
> and on July 16, 2020, these measures were extended until August 20,
> 2020. On August 14, 2020, these measure were once again extended through September 21, 2020. On September 18, 2020, these measures were
> again extended **until October 21, 2020**.
>
> The U.S., Mexican, and Canadian governments are taking necessary
> action to fight against this pandemic together.

More info on using land borders: https://ca.usembassy.gov/travel-restrictions-fact-sheet/ (note "U.S. citizens, lawful permanent residents, and individuals with valid travel documents will be exempted.", some definition of essential travel, and reduced border hours)